# I can't run my jar files from the Java control panel

Tags: java

I tried to run my application from the java control panel, but I got this error message.

[image]

So I tried to whitelist file:// but it won't me allow to do it. How can I let my computer run without issues the jar locally stored?

[image]

Comment: What is the source of this JAR?  Do you know what version of Java was used to build it?

Comment: I programmed the application with: Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201705191307)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2
Java: 1.8.0_101; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.101-b13
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_101-b13
System: Windows 8.1 version 6.3 running on amd64; MS932; en_GB (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2
Cache directory: C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2

Answer (score 0):

To make it work I had to add to exceptions file:/// with three slashes.